# Typescript: access nested object values through keys defined in array

Tags: javascript, typescript, keyof

I was wondering how I could make the error on this [LINK](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBKEDGB7ATgEwLwG8BQUhUAlhgFwDOwaxAdgOYDcBRAbgIYA2ArhJdXSZ4AvnlCRYIACrgIuFoXZk4iVJmZEoAI2UJk6DBqJJ+NBgBoFUclTP1LovKlpUoHTqXbBoWKAAo0XRlIAEosAD58TWdXAGsIEAosAG0AInZU81StVIBdI0IAM3R-GOAoeJAoFEKKhIoQqM0iYkKA5Mqodgo6kBrJYIhcgDp3XgBCLCxU1Ma8K01RRas0CGBuNFooal4RIA) disappear.

tl;dr I have a type that has both nested properties(object) and regular ones(string,boolean etc.). I am trying to check if nested values are non empty strings. But considering there are many of them I am using a string array with the type keys that should be checked. I am looking for a solution that will not force me to split the defined type into separate types and then just merging them together.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: ADDED CODE AND UPDATED TYPESCRIPT PLAYGROUND LINK

```
type MyRecord={
    id:string;
    value:string;
}
type MyType={
    a:MyRecord;
    b:MyRecord;
    c:string,
    d:string,
}

const validate = (r:MyType)=>{
    const keys=["a","b"];
    for (const key of keys){
        if(r[key as keyof MyType].value!==""){
           return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Thrown error:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string | MyRecord'. Did you mean 'valueOf'?
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Comment: do you mean to remove the error? You will have to paste some code in your question and explain visually.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBKEDGB7ATgEwLwG8BQUhUAlhgFwDOwaxAdgOYDcBRAbgIYA2ArhJdXSZ4AvnlCRYIACrgIuFoXZk4iVJmZEoAI2UJk6DBqJJA20Nko3WgGtaKAO61mwoA

Comment: That link does not work. We cannot see your code example. Please [edit] your question, fix the link _and_ also include your code in the question so that future readers may benefit from your question.

Comment: Added the code and updated the playground link, plus added the thrown typescript error. Hopefully the link saved the changes this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having `keys` as a `string[]` you could add a `as const` to make the type `readonly ["a", "b"]`

```
const validate = (r:MyType)=>{
    const keys=["a","b"] as const;
    for (const key of keys){
        if(r[key].value!==""){

        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. And found only one way to resolve this

```
type MyRecord = {
    id:string;
    value:string;
} & string

type StrObj = {
    a: MyRecord,
    b: MyRecord,
    c: MyRecord,
    d: MyRecord,
}

type A = keyof StrObj


const validate = (r:StrObj)=>{
    const keys: Array<A> = ["a" ,"b"]
    for (const key of keys) {
        if (r[key].value) {

        }
    }
    return true
}
```

In my opinion looks like not the best way... But works.
Recently I tried to find other solution, but looks like there is no other solution

Comment: Yeah works, kinda wanted to avoid doing something like this...